# Drupal 8 , render Twig from string with twig functions

Tags: php, function, twig, drupal-8

Hello i use Drupal 8 twig and it cant catch his functions.

```
$TwigString = '<div>{{result}}{% include "some.html.twig" with {somevars:vars}%}</div>';
$Twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$Twig->setLoader(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$html = $Twig->render($TwigString,array("result" => "Success!"));
```

I got this :

Success!some.html.twig

What should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be interested in the `inline_template` functionality now in Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/node/2311123

The reason you are having difficulty troubleshooting is because you loaded up a brand new Twig environment with only the string loader. If all you have is the string loader, you can't include files like `include "some.html.twig"` because you don't have the `Filesystem` loader available.

See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2369981) for how we improved our use of the string loader in Drupal core for the case of inline templates, because the string loader will literally pass everything through and it makes it hard to troubleshoot.

`inline_template` should theoretically allow you to combine the string loader with the other loaders.

Also as an aside for includes/extends/etc. you have a few main options in Drupal 8 as of this writing (March 2015):

- Namespace support for theme and module templates: `@mymodule/file.html.twig`
- [Registry loader](https://www.drupal.org/node/2381103) for templates registered with [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/search/8/hook_theme): `file.html.twig`
- Full path relative to the root: `modules/mymodule/templates/file.html.twig`